# Why ADD is 4 cycles on Z80?

Tags: z80, cpu-cycles

I use this ALU block diagram as a learning material : http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html

I am not familiar with electronics. I am currently believing that a clock cycle is needed to move data from registers or latch to another register or latch, eventually throught a net of logical gates.

So here is my understanding of what happens for and ADD :

- Cycle 1 : move registers to internal latchs
- Cycle 2 : move low nibbles internal latchs to internal result latch (through the ALU)
- Cycle 3, in parallell :

  - move high nibbles internal latchs to destination register (through the ALU)
  - move internal result latch to register

I think operations cycle 3 are done in parallell because there are two 4 bits bus (for high and low nibbles) and the register bus seems to be 8 bits.

Comment: Oh boy ! I think my Cycle 1 is actually 2 cycles. Since the register bus is 8 bits it can't load 2 registers at once ! Is that it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the z80 data sheet](http://www.z80.info/zip/z80cpu_um.pdf):

> The PC is placed on the address bus at the beginning of the M1 cycle.
>   One half clock cycle later the MREQ signal goes active. At this time
>   the address to the memory has had time to stabilize so that the
>   falling edge of MREQ can be used directly as a chip enable clock to
>   dynamic memories. The RD line also goes active to indicate that the
>   memory read data should be enabled onto the CPU data bus. The CPU
>   samples the data from the memory on the data bus with the rising edge
>   of the clock of state T3 and this same edge is used by the CPU to turn
>   off the RD and MREQ signals. Thus, the data has already been sampled
>   by the CPU before the RD signal becomes inactive. Clock state T3 and
>   T4 of a fetch cycle are used to refresh dynamic memories. The CPU uses
>   this time to decode and execute the fetched instruction so that no
>   other operation could be performed at this time.

So it appears mostly to be about memory interfacing to read the opcode rather than actually doing the addition — decode and execution occurs entirely within clock states T3 and T4. Given that the z80 [has a 4-bit ALU](http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html), it would take two operations to perform an 8-bit addition. Which likely explains the use of two cycles.

Comment: So T3 is used to decode the instruction and T4 is used to execute it. Thus the addition takes place in one clock cycle. And, no, the Z-80 has an 8 bit  ALU and a 16 bit adder. The 4 bit alu link above is a dead link.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri no, the Z80 has a 4-bit ALU. Link fixed. If you don't believe that link, see page 10 of http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Oral_History/Zilog_Z80/102658073.05.01.pdf — that's direct from the mouth of the designers.